# Python equivalent of Java DataInputStream.readUTF()

Tags: android, python, sockets

I am working on an Android application which communicates with Python based server. I'm using sockets for communication. Android application sends data in JSON format using DataOutputStream.writeUTF(). Code for sending data is as follows

```
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                   socket.getOutputStream());
    JSONObject jsonData=new JSONObject();
    jsonData.put("request", "signin");
    dataOutputStream.writeUTF(jsonData.toString());
```

I'm facing problem that DataOutputStream.writeUTF() writes two bytes at start of data which is length of data sent. For receiving data in server side I have to do 2 reads first for getting length of data and second to get actual data. Code for receiving data in Python is as follows

```
    data = conn_stream.recv(2)
    data_length=struct.unpack('>H',data)[0]
    data=conn_stream.recv(data_length)
```

Is there any Python equivalent of Java DataInputStream.readUTF()?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The below `DataInputStream` class provides (almost) all of the methods defined in Javas DataInputStream for reading primitive Java data types from an input stream including `readUTF()` method.

```
"""
Reading from Java DataInputStream format.
"""

import struct

class DataInputStream:
    def __init__(self, stream):
        self.stream = stream

    def read_boolean(self):
        return struct.unpack('?', self.stream.read(1))[0]

    def read_byte(self):
        return struct.unpack('b', self.stream.read(1))[0]

    def read_unsigned_byte(self):
        return struct.unpack('B', self.stream.read(1))[0]

    def read_char(self):
        return chr(struct.unpack('>H', self.stream.read(2))[0])

    def read_double(self):
        return struct.unpack('>d', self.stream.read(8))[0]

    def read_float(self):
        return struct.unpack('>f', self.stream.read(4))[0]

    def read_short(self):
        return struct.unpack('>h', self.stream.read(2))[0]

    def read_unsigned_short(self):
        return struct.unpack('>H', self.stream.read(2))[0]

    def read_long(self):
        return struct.unpack('>q', self.stream.read(8))[0]

    def read_utf(self):
        utf_length = struct.unpack('>H', self.stream.read(2))[0]
        return self.stream.read(utf_length)

    def read_int(self):
        return struct.unpack('>i', self.stream.read(4))[0]
```

**Example:**

```
with open('/tmp/stream', 'rb') as f:
    dis = DataInputStream(f)
    val = dis.read_int()
    string = dis.read_utf()
```

**Note:** You should note that the class has no exception handling and might not be accurate in the way it handles UTF-strings with NULL characters.

Source code from [here](https://github.com/arngarden/python_java_datastream).